# Postgres: FATAL:  catalog is missing 1 attribute(s) for relid 2653

Tags: postgresql

Новичок в postgres, но вот такой трабл. Установил postgres и создал одну базу данных. Все работало. Но сегодня с утра сделал еще одну, и начался какой-то косяк.

```
:~$ createdb fortest --owner=postgres
:~$ psql -U postgres fortest
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

и

```
postgres=# \connect fortest 
FATAL:  catalog is missing 1 attribute(s) for relid 2653
Previous connection kept
```

В инете ничего не нашел, в чем может быть трабл?

Comment: в сети достаточно много ответов на 2рой вопрос https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=postgresql%20catalog%20is%20missing%201%20attribute%20for%20relid, но я думаю вам нужнее просто создать тестовую БД?

postgres=# CREATE DATABASE test2;

Comment: Не один из этих советов не решили мою проблему. Отчего-то к одной базе данных я спокойно подключаюсь, а вот к новым не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему добавив pg
`:~$ sudo npm install pg`